# Cant connect to ray head node from another local machine

Tags: python, windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ray

i'm new in ml and trying to use 2 window 10 computers in local network, starting docker desktop with wsl2 on both, on first mashine (192.9.200.111) starting ray head node in container with -p 6379:6379 -p 8265:8265 options, then using "netsh interface portproxy" for this ports to portproxy them from wsl to host. And finally, on another computer (192.9.200.113) do the same things, but starting ray as worker "ray start address='192.9.200.111:6379' " and cant connect to gcs server, however i have an access to ray dashboard on 192.9.200.111:8265 address. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you get into other machine and check if you can access the port 6379? Also, you need to make sure to open all ports here; https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/configure.html#ports-configurations

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in wsl subsystem, looks like docker desktop create vm with random ip,windows create eth virtual interface also with random ip, and there is a big problem to route all this stuff correctly.